# Retrieving events from a Firebase database

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: (the link to my code)]I am currently trying to use Firebase as a backend for an iOS app. I am able to log custom parameters but how do I retrieve these events from my Firebase database?

Comment: show what have you done so far . your code , your efforts

Comment: This is my code for logging events. I have no idea where to start for retrieving events. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:storedBeacon.major
                          parameters:@{
                                       @"uuid":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"id-%@", storedBeacon.uuid],
                                       @"average rssi":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"average rssi-%@", storedBeacon.ave_rssi]
                                       }];